# SQL - Sum of two values IN a Group By

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to add two values or get sum of two values and show it under one Exchange Name. Data below:

```
Table
--------------------------------------------------
EXCHANGE NAME       CODE        TURNOVER    TRADEDATE
PARIS               PA            12        14-NOV-2019
SWISS               SW            14        14-NOV-2019
NULL                SA             2        14-NOV-2019
NULL                MI             2        14-NOV-2019
MILAN               MI_1           3        14-NOV-2019

My Query
----------------------------------------------------
SELECT CE.EXCHANGE_NAME, sum(CE.TURNOVER)  
FROM CE
WHERE CE.tradedate = '14-NOV-2019'
GROUP BY CE.EXCHANGE_NAME

Result
-----------------------------------------------------
EXCHANGE NAME       SUM
PARIS               12
SWISS               14
MILAN               3
```

What I would like to achieve is that the total for SWISS to be 16 and MILAN to be 5 as MI belongs to MILAN also. There are NULL Values for EXCHANGE NAME but they belong to a certain exchange (Swiss in this case and Milan) i.e. code SA belongs to SWISS and MI belongs to MILAN.

How can I accommodate this in my query for situation like SWISS and MILAN where I know which code belongs to EXCHANGE_NAME?

Many thanks

Comment: What if other `EXCHANGE NAME` has `NULL` value ?

Comment: you would have to use the lead and lag function over here

Comment: @YogeshSharma that is the case I have two other exchanges which have a similar issue and I need a solution that will help me cater to those scenarios.

Comment: Why can;t you just group by code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COALESCE()` to turn `NULL` values of `EXCHANGE_NAME` to `'SWISS'`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(CE.EXCHANGE_NAME, 'SWISS'), sum(CE.TURNOVER)  
FROM CE
WHERE CE.tradedate = '14-NOV-2019'
GROUP BY COALESCE(CE.EXCHANGE_NAME, 'SWISS')
```

---

**Edit**: you can use handy Oracle function `decode()` to map the `code` to a default `EXCHANGE_NAME`:

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(
        CE.EXCHANGE_NAME, 
        DECODE(CE.CODE, 'SA', 'SWISS', 'MI_1', 'MILAN')
    ) EXCHANGE, 
    SUM(CE.TURNOVER)  
FROM CE
WHERE CE.tradedate = '14-NOV-2019'
GROUP BY COALESCE(
        CE.EXCHANGE_NAME, 
        DECODE(CE.CODE, 'SA', 'SWISS', 'MI_1', 'MILAN')
    )
```

You can expand the `DECODE()` argument as needed for your use case.

Comment: What if other `EXCHANGE NAME` has `NULL` value ?

Comment: OP said : *There are NULL Values for EXCHANGE NAME but they belong to a certain exchange (Swiss in this case)*.

Comment: @GMB I have this issue with other exchanges as well. Sorry I have edited the question.

Comment: @AM_86: So how do we determine to which exchange `NULL` values should be assigned?

Comment: @GMB Based on the CODE...I'll edit the question the further.

Comment: @AM_86: I updated my answer with a new solution according to your edited question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(CE.EXCHANGE_NAME, 'SWISS') as EXCHANGE_NAME, SUM(CE.TURNOVER)  
FROM CE
WHERE CE.tradedate = '14-NOV-2019'
GROUP BY COALESCE(CE.EXCHANGE_NAME, 'SWISS');
```

As a note:  I like the use of `DATE` for date constants:

```
WHERE CE.tradedate = DATE '2019-11-14'
```

This allows the use of ISO standard date formatting.

EDIT:

Use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN CE.CODE = 'SA' THEN 'SWISS'
             WHEN CE.CODE = 'MI_1' THEN 'MILAN'
             ELSE CE.EXCHANGE_NAME
        END) as EXCHANGE_NAME,
       SUM(CE.TURNOVER)  
FROM CE
WHERE CE.tradedate = DATE '2019-11-14'
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN CE.CODE = 'SA' THEN 'SWISS'
               WHEN CE.CODE = 'MI_1' THEN 'MILAN'
               ELSE CE.EXCHANGE_NAME
          END);
```

Comment: What if other `EXCHANGE NAME` has `NULL` value ?

Comment: @YogeshSharma . . . The OP explicitly states:  "There are NULL Values for EXCHANGE NAME but they belong to a certain exchange (Swiss in this case) i.e. code SA belongs to SWISS."

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry, yes that is the case I should have specified and edited the question, I have similar issue with other exchanges as well.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Hi Gordon, are you able to help please?

Answer (score 0):

To me, it looks like you have to create a **mapping** table which will map codes to exchange names:

```
SQL> create table exmap
  2    (exchange_name varchar2(20),
  3     code          varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> insert into exmap
  2    select 'PARIS', 'PA'   from dual union all
  3    select 'SWISS', 'SW'   from dual union all
  4    select 'SWISS', 'SA'   from dual union all
  5    select 'MILAN', 'MI'   from dual union all
  6    select 'MILAN', 'MI_1' from dual;

5 rows created.

SQL>
```

Now, with date in the `CE` table (the one you posted), you'd join those two tables:

```
SQL> select e.exchange_name,
  2         sum(c.turnover) sum_turnover
  3  from ce c join exmap e on e.code = c.code
  4  group by e.exchange_name;

EXCHANGE_NAME        SUM_TURNOVER
-------------------- ------------
PARIS                          12
MILAN                           5
SWISS                          16

SQL>
```

Why such an approach? Because sooner or later you'll add something like this to the `CE` table (so PARIS will now be 20):

```
SQL> insert into ce values ('PARIS', 'PR', 8);

1 row created.
```

Now, if you choose to maintain the mapping within the code, you'll have to fix it **everywhere**, in all your stored procedures, reports, forms ... whatever uses that table, and add yet another `CASE`, e.g.

```
case when code in ('PA', 'PR') then 'PARIS'
     ...                 ^^^^
                         this
```

That might drive you mad. But, if you simply add it to the mapping table:

```
SQL> insert into exmap values ('PARIS', 'PR');

1 row created.
```

the "old" *join* query will work without any further action:

```
SQL> select e.exchange_name,
  2         sum(c.turnover) sum_turnover
  3  from ce c join exmap e on e.code = c.code
  4  group by e.exchange_name;

EXCHANGE_NAME        SUM_TURNOVER
-------------------- ------------
PARIS                          20
MILAN                           5
SWISS                          16

SQL>
```